# How to open a Lotus Notes New mail and send

Tags: excel, macros, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Ive seen a couple of macro's for Loading up Lotus Notes and putting an attachment in and sending it off. 
Its almost finished it sends the email, but dont know how to send a folder, it works with a PDF file, but I have a bunch of PDF files in a folder which i want to send. 
How do i format the email to read:
"
Hello

Please Find Attachment

(Attachment)

Signature 
"

Any Help is appreciated,   Thanks

```
 Sub SendEmail()
 Dim WatchRange As Range
 Dim IntersectRange As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim UserName As String
Dim MailDbName As String
Dim Recipient As Variant
Dim Maildb As Object
Dim MailDoc As Object
Dim Attachment As String
Dim Session As Object
Dim stSignature As String
With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
' Open and locate current LOTUS NOTES User
Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
UserName = Session.UserName
MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1,           UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)
If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
Else
Maildb.OPENMAIL
End If
' Create New Mail and Address Title Handlers
 Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
 MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
 Maildb.GetProfileDocument("CalendarProfile").GetItemValue("Signature")(0)
' Select range of e-mail addresses
 MailDoc.SendTo = "joe bloggs"
 MailDoc.subject = "Work"
 MailDoc.Body = "Hello" & " " & " Please find attachment."
 MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True
 Attachment = "c:\03-11\4267.pdf"
 If Attachment <> "" Then

    Set AttachME = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Attachment")
    Set EmbedObj = AttachME.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", Attachment, "")
    On Error Resume Next
    MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM ("Attachment")
End If

  MailDoc.PostedDate = Now()
  On Error GoTo errorhandler1
 MailDoc.SEND 0, Recipient
 Set Maildb = Nothing
 Set MailDoc = Nothing
 Set Session = Nothing
 .ScreenUpdating = True
 .DisplayAlerts = True
  On Error GoTo errorhandler1
  Set Maildb = Nothing
  Set MailDoc = Nothing
  Set Session = Nothing
 End With
 End Sub
```

I have altered my macro, It nows add the signature but the format is wrong and it doesn't attach the file.

```
    Sub SendEmail()

  Dim WatchRange As Range
  Dim IntersectRange As Range
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim UserName As String
  Dim MailDbName As String
  Dim Recipient As Variant
 Dim Maildb As Object
 Dim MailDoc As Object
 Dim Attachment As String
 Dim Session As Object
  Dim stSignature As String
 Dim ws As Object 'Lotus Workspace


  Dim objProfile As Object
  Dim rtiSig As Object, rtitem As Object, rtiNew As Object
  Dim uiMemo As Object
  Dim strToArray() As String, strCCArray() As String, strBccArray() As String
 Dim strTo As String, strCC As String, strBcc As String, _
 strObject As String, strBody As String, strAttachment As String, blnSaveit As   Boolean
   Dim strSignText As String, strMemoUNID As String
   Dim intSignOption As Integer


  With Application
  .ScreenUpdating = False
   .DisplayAlerts = False
   ' Open and locate current LOTUS NOTES User
   Set Session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
   Set ws = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")

   UserName = Session.UserName
     MailDbName = Left$(UserName, 1) & Right$(UserName, (Len(UserName) - InStr(1, UserName, " "))) & ".nsf"
    Set Maildb = Session.GETDATABASE("", MailDbName)
    If Maildb.IsOpen = True Then
    Else
     Maildb.OPENMAIL
    End If
    ' Create New Mail and Address Title Handlers


    Set MailDoc = Maildb.CREATEDOCUMENT
     MailDoc.Form = "Memo"
   stSignature =                        Maildb.GetProfileDocument("CalendarProfile").GetItemValue("Signature")(0)
  ' Select range of e-mail addresses
    MailDoc.SendTo = "JJunoir"
     MailDoc.subject = ""
     MailDoc.Body = "Hello" & " " & " Please find attachment,"
      MailDoc.SAVEMESSAGEONSEND = True


      Set objProfile = Maildb.GETPROFILEDOCUMENT("CalendarProfile")
      intSignOption = objProfile.GETITEMVALUE("SignatureOption")(0)
      strSignText = objProfile.GETITEMVALUE("Signature")(0)


      Attachment = "c:\Debit Notes 03-11\"
     If strAttachment <> "" Then
    Set AttachME = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Attachment")
    Set EmbedObj = AttachME.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", strAttachment,     "Attachment")
    On Error Resume Next
    MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM ("Attachment")
    End If


   'Open memo in ui
   Set uiMemo = ws.EDITDOCUMENT(True, MailDoc)
   Call uiMemo.GotoField("Body")

   'Check if the signature is automatically inserted
   If objProfile.GETITEMVALUE("EnableSignature")(0) <> 1 Then
   If intSignOption = 2 Then
   Call uiMemo.ImportItem(objProfile, "Signature_Rich")
    End If
    End If

   Call uiMemo.GotoField("Body")
   'Save the mail doc
   strMemoUNID = uiMemo.DOCUMENT.UNIVERSALID
    uiMemo.DOCUMENT.MailOptions = "0"
   Call uiMemo.Save
   uiMemo.DOCUMENT.SaveOptions = "0"
   Call uiMemo.Close
   Set uiMemo = Nothing
   Set MailDoc = Nothing

   'Get the text and the signature
   Set MailDoc = Maildb.GETDOCUMENTBYUNID(strMemoUNID)
   Set rtiSig = MailDoc.GETFIRSTITEM("Body")
   Set rtiNew = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("rtiTemp")
   Call rtiNew.APPENDTEXT(strBody)
   Call rtiNew.APPENDTEXT(Chr(10)): Call rtiNew.APPENDTEXT(Chr(10))
   Call rtiNew.APPENDRTITEM(rtiSig)
  'Remove actual body to replace it with the new one
  Call MailDoc.RemoveItem("Body")
  Set rtitem = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Body")
  Call rtitem.APPENDRTITEM(rtiNew)

  MailDoc.Save False, False
  Set uiMemo = ws.EDITDOCUMENT(True, MailDoc)


   MailDoc.PostedDate = Now()
   On Error GoTo errorhandler1
   MailDoc.SEND 0, Recipient
   Set Maildb = Nothing
   Set MailDoc = Nothing
   Set Session = Nothing
  .ScreenUpdating = True
  .DisplayAlerts = True
  errorhandler1:
  Set Maildb = Nothing
  Set MailDoc = Nothing
  Set Session = Nothing
  End With
  End Sub
```

This is what it produces with no attachment 
Kind Regards 
J JuniorHello  Please find attachment,

Comment: I have updated the previous macro to this new macro. Can someone explain this line  Set AttachME = MailDoc.CREATERICHTEXTITEM("Attachment")
        Set EmbedObj = AttachME.EMBEDOBJECT(1454, "", Attachment, "")

Comment: This now adds in a newline   MailDoc.Body = "Hello" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " Please find attachment," & vbNewLine.   I'm still trying to look for a solution to add in a signature.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to manipulate the Lotus Notes client user interface, then you started half correctly by using "Notes.NotesSession" instead of "Lotus.NotesSession". The "Notes." prefix gets you the [OLE classes](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_USING_NOTES_CLASSES_IN_VISUAL_BASIC.html) instead of the COM classes that you would have gotten with the "Lotus" prefix, and you definitely need to be using the OLE classes - but you still chose the wrong root object.

The NotesSession class and all the classes that descend from it, which are available in both the OLE and COM classes, are referred to as "back-end classes", which means they do not manipulate the user interface at all.

You need to use the "front-end classes" if you want to manipulate the UI, and the root object for that is "[Notes.NotesUIWorkspace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESUIWORKSPACE_CLASS.html)".  In many cases, you may find that you want a combination of the back-end and front-end classes. For example, the [NotesUIWorkspace.EditDocument](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EDITDOCUMENT_METHOD.html) (front-end) takes a [NotesDocument](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDOCUMENT_CLASS.html) (back-end) argument, allowing you to open the UI for a document that you located by going behind the scenes to find it.

Comment: Now its doesn't work with Line Username=Session.Username. Run time error 438. Object doesn't support this properly. What could I change it to?

Comment: If you need/want to use both UI classes (to manipulate the user interface) and backend classes (to get username fromthe NotesSession object) you need to instantiate both.

Comment: Which session class are you using now? Notes.NotesSesison or Lotus.NotesSession? Have you tried the Username proprety with both of them?

Comment: Richard, I have change my macro altogether now, but the above issue is fixed now.

Comment: One of the basic principles that makes a community like StackOverflow work is that if you ask for help from others, and then you solve your problem, you should be willing to share the details of how you solved it so that other people can learn from your experience. Please consider posting your own answer to your question, describing how you fixed the problem and including your updated code.

Comment: Right sorry about, I will be doing that in future from now on